# Separating code from javafx start method

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I want to separate the two FOR loops under into **generateBricks()** and **addBricks()** possibly in a separate class but I don't know how to do this separation as the loops use rectangle class for shape and also try to add the bricks to the dispay.. Any ideas guys?

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    //Just setting up the graphics for the game including the bar and ball
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root , 400 , 500);

    Rectangle[][] bricks = new Rectangle[10][3];

    //Generating individual rectangle objects to add to brick array
    for(int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < bricks[0].length; j++)
        {
            bricks[i][j] = new Rectangle(10 + (40 * i), 70 + (20 * j), 30, 10);
        }
    }   

    //Iterating through the array of bricks and adding them to the graphics
    for(int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < bricks[0].length; j++)
        {
            root.getChildren().add(bricks[i][j]);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Your method signatures should (probably) look like `private Rectangle[][] generateBricks(int numRows, int numColumns)` and `private void addBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks, Pane pane)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Pane root;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        //Just setting up the graphics for the game including the bar and ball
        root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 500);

        Rectangle[][] bricks = new Rectangle[10][3];

        bricks = generateBricks(bricks);
        addBricks(bricks);
    }

    public Rectangle[][] generateBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks) {
        //Generating individual rectangle objects to add to brick array
        for (int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bricks[0].length; j++) {
                bricks[i][j] = new Rectangle(10 + (40 * i), 70 + (20 * j), 30, 10);
            }
        }
        return bricks;
    }

    public void generateBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks) {
        //Iterating through the array of bricks and adding them to the graphics
        for (int i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bricks[0].length; j++) {
                root.getChildren().add(bricks[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note:**
>   Made `Pane root;` global
>   Put both `for`into different methods

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to separate out the methods, think about what each method should do, what information it needs to do that, and what information it should provide back to whoever calls it.

Your `generateBricks()` method should, given its name, be responsible for creating the bricks, and it should return those bricks (as an array) back to the caller. You probably want the method to be told how many bricks to create (instead of hard-coding it, or relying on a global variable). So the signature of the method should probably be

```
private Rectangle[][] generateBricks(int numCols, int numRows) ;
```

and the implementation will look something like

```
private Rectangle[][] generateBricks(int numCols, int numRows) {
    Rectangle[][] bricks = new Rectangle[numCols][numRows];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < numRows ; j++) {
            bricks[i][j] = new Rectangle(10 + (40 * i), 70 + (20 * j), 30, 10);
        }
    }
    return bricks ;
}
```

Your `addBricks()` method needs to add bricks to a container of some kind; so the information it needs is an array of bricks and a container. It's just going to do its work, and doesn't need to provide any information back to whoever calls it. So its signature will be

```
private void addBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks, Pane container) ;
```

and it just looks like:

```
private void addBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks, Pane container) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < bricks.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; i < bricks[i].length ; j++) {
            container.getChildren().add(bricks[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can make this a bit more elegant using a for-each type loop:

```
private void addBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks, Pane container) {
    for (Rectangle[] column : bricks) {
        for (Rectangle brick : column) {
            container.getChildren().add(brick);
        }
    }
}
```

or even take advantage of the `addAll(...)` method (which takes a one-dimensional array):

```
private void addBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks, Pane container) {
    for (Rectangle[] column : bricks) {
        container.getChildren().addAll(column);
    }
}
```

So all together this looks like

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        //Just setting up the graphics for the game including the bar and ball
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root , 400 , 500);

        Rectangle[][] bricks = generateBricks(10, 3);
        addBricks(bricks, root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Rectangle[][] generateBricks(int numCols, int numRows) {
        Rectangle[][] bricks = new Rectangle[numCols][numRows];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < numRows ; j++) {
                bricks[i][j] = new Rectangle(10 + (40 * i), 70 + (20 * j), 30, 10);
            }
        }
        return bricks ;
    }

    private void addBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks, Pane container) {
        for (Rectangle[] column : bricks) {
            container.getChildren().addAll(column);
        }
    }

}
```

---

If you want to go a step further, and separate things out into different classes, I think the first thing to think about is something called the ["single responsibility principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). This basically says that each class should be responsible for a single aspect of the functionality of the application. You already violate this principle, because the `Application` subclass is responsible for the lifecycle of the application (which is why it has a method called `start()`, which is invoked when the application starts, as well as other methods you probably don't need, such as `init()` and `stop()`). Right now, your `Main` class is handling the lifecycle of the application, as well as being responsible for designing the display (or "view"). So you could extract the second responsibility into its own class:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class BrickView extends Pane {

    public BrickView() {
        Rectangle[][] bricks = generateBricks(10, 3);
        addBricks(bricks);
    }


    private Rectangle[][] generateBricks(int numCols, int numRows) {
        Rectangle[][] bricks = new Rectangle[numCols][numRows];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < numRows ; j++) {
                bricks[i][j] = new Rectangle(10 + (40 * i), 70 + (20 * j), 30, 10);
            }
        }
        return bricks ;
    }

    private void addBricks(Rectangle[][] bricks) {
        for (Rectangle[] column : bricks) {
            this.getChildren().addAll(column);
        }
    }
}
```

and now your `Main` class can focus on what it should be doing: starting up the application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        //Just setting up the graphics for the game including the bar and ball
        BrickView brickView = new BrickView();
        Scene scene = new Scene(brickView , 400 , 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

You could even go further, and create a `BrickFactory` class, which was responsible for creating the bricks, and separate that functionality from the view that decides how to display them. That's probably overkill here (though it does have some advantages in general).